# gem uninstall rake-10.1.0 error (couldnt remove from gem list and im trying to use rake-0.8.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

gem list shows rake (10.1.0, 0.8.3),trying to uninstall rake 10.1.0 by gem uninstall rake -v '10.1.0' getting ..INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed showing rake 10.1.0 in gem list...my goal is to use rake-0.8.3 So any one can help (using rails-2.3.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you just do `gem uninstall rake`, you should then be prompted to determine which version you'd like to uninstall. I'd just do that and uninstall all of the versions that you're not wanting to use.

Another solution might be to just specify which version of rake you'd like to use in your `gemfile`.